# Why does a python-on-whales docker mysql command not work, but issuing the command in the shell does

Tags: python, mysql, bash, docker, python-on-whales

I am using python-on-whales to run a mysql command in a mysql docker conatiner.

I use `docker.execute` to call the command inside the container from a python script, and it returns an error:

```py
import mysql.connector
import os
from mysql.connector.errors import DatabaseError
from python_on_whales import docker

envs={"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD":"TempPassword",
              "MYSQL_USER":"root",
              "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD":"TempPassword"
                }
#Start the mysql container       
docker.run("mysql/mysql-server",name="test_mysql",
                    envs=envs,
                    publish=[(3306,3306)],
                    detach=True)
#copy scripts to container
docker.copy("./permissions.mysql","test_mysql:/etc/") 
docker.copy("./permissions.sh","test_mysql:/etc/")
#try calling permissions.sh on the container
docker.execute("test_mysql", ["/etc/permissions.sh"])
```

This produced the following error:

```sh
    result = run(full_cmd, tty=tty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/python_on_whales/utils.py", line 150, in run
    raise DockerException(
python_on_whales.exceptions.DockerException: The docker command executed was `/usr/local/bin/docker exec test_mysql /etc/permissions.sh`.
It returned with code 1
The content of stdout is ''
The content of stderr is 'mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

In the error python-on-whales reports the command that it called:

`/usr/local/bin/docker exec test_mysql /etc/permissions.sh`

But if I issue the command reported back from python-on-whales directly in the bash shell, rather than using python-on-whales the command executes.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything Docker-specific here, provided you started the database with a `docker run -p ...:3306` option to publish the database port to the host.  Use the ordinary MySQL client library to connect to that published port.

Comment: The `docker.run(...)` command from python-on-whales is essentially caling `docker run -p`.

Answer (score 0):

Realised the issue.

python_on_whales doesn't automatically wait for the container with the server to be up before trying to run the script - which was the root of my problem. I no longer need to run the script, as what it does (allow me to access the server from outside the conatiner) can be handled with the correct argument to the connection set-up:

```py
        #set up test server and database:
        envs={"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD":"TempPassword",
              "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST":"%",
              "MYSQL_USER":"root",
                }
```

But python_on_whales not waiting caused a few other issues in my code. So for anyone that it may be useful for you can do something similar to this waiting until the connection returns `True` like so:

```py
        not_connected=True
        while not_connected:
            try:
                connection=mysql.connector.connect(**config)
                if connection.is_connected():
                    not_connected=False
            except:
                time.sleep(1)
                pass
```